# How do I tell IntelliJ IDEA where to find python packages for sublime text 2 plugin development?

Tags: python, intellij-idea, sublimetext2, sublime-text-plugin

I am developing a sublime text 2 plugin and my choice for python development is IntelliJ IDEA with the python plugin (more or less the same as PyCharm).

Now IntellJ tells me it doesn't find the libraries that I import. That code is working in sublime text 2 as a plugin, so somehow I just need to tell IntelliJ IDEA where to look. Does anyone know how to specify these paths?

[image: Missing imports for sublime plugin development]

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Is it not able to find any library or just sublime related library...

Comment: Any library. For example `math` is also not found.

Comment: Did the answer solve your problem.....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add Python sdk to your your Project Structure.If you are using linux python sdk path is `/usr/bin/python2.7`
For windows it is where you installed your python

```
File -> Project Structure -> Project -> Project SDK -> new
```

and select the installation path of your Python interpreter

Comment: Yep, that helped with the standard libraries - now still missing the sublime text plugin specific libraries. Any ideas?